# SkSpriteNode won't show up

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    var sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
    sun.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    sun.xScale = 0.2
    sun.yScale = 0.2
    addChild(sun)
}
```

I'm new to coding games, but I've worked with swift, and i just added this to my code and my sun will not show up, there isn't an error, and do have a image name Sun in images.xcassets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your GameViewController-frame fits your GameScene-frame.

Just add this line to your GameViewController.swift-class in the `viewDidLoad`-method before the `skView.presentScene(scene)`:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

Here you make sure that the frames are the same and that your `.position` works like you want.